# Swap Text in AngularJs data binding for Font Awesome font when text match (Social Media Fonts)

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How can I (using either `AngularJs` or `HTML`), swap my returned text for a `Font Awesome font` when the text matches a certain string?

**For example**: If my `{{profileData.channels}}` returns the following string:
**Twitter**, **YouTube** and **Facebook** - how can I substitute these for the **Font Awesome fonts**; `fa fa-twitter-square`; `fa fa-youtube-square`; `fa fa-facebook-square`

Below is my `<div>` where I would like to display these:

```
<div class="mentionsMeta">
    <div>
        <h2>Channels></i></h2>
        <hr>
        <span class="itemInfo">{{profileData.channels}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking at a logic like this.

```
<span class="itemInfo {{ profileData.channels === 'Twitter' ? 'fa fa-twitter-square' : '' }}">{{profileData.channels === 'Twitter' ? '' : profileData.channels}}</span>
```

Of course you can make this much better, for example you can change your `profileData` array of string with an array of objects where you set the corresponding class, so that you will have something like

```
<span ng-if="profileData.isSpecial" class="itemInfo {{profileData.channels}}"></span>
<span ng-if="!profileData.isSpecial" class="itemInfo">{{profileData.channels}}</span>
```

Comment: I think it is best to modify my returned objects. But either will work.Thank you!